# The name `row` does not exist in the current context error

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, email

I want to send mail to dynamic users, based on the parameters as

```
row["userName"].ToString()
```

I used the above code like this in my code,

```
foreach (var row in group)
{
    sbodyMail += "<tr>" +
        "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + row["userName"].ToString() + " </td> " +
        "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + row["Doc_Type"].ToString() + " </td> " +
        "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + row["CountofDocNo"].ToString() + " </td> " +
        "</tr>";
}
sbodyMail += "</table><br>" + //close of header
"<b>THIS IS A SYSTEM GENERATED MAIL. PLEASE DO NOT REPLY </b>";
string strExp = "";
string startupPath = "";
List<string> ls_attach1 = new List<string>();
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
startupPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
strExp = "RAName = '" + group.Key + "'";
DataTable dtNew = ds.Tables[1].Select(strExp).CopyToDataTable();
DataSet dsNew = new DataSet();
dsNew.Tables.Add(dtNew);

ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook(startupPath + "\\Attachment\\Reminder_Sheet.xls", dsNew);
ls_attach1.Add(startupPath + "\\Attachment\\Reminder_Sheet.xls");
foreach (var attach in ls_attach1)
{
    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attach));
}

ce.SendEmail(row["userName"].ToString(), "", "", "Information on documents for processing", sbodyMail, "AUTOSQL", "Powersoft", ls_attach1, "ConnectionString");
```

But I get error:

> The name `row` does not exist in the current context error

Comment: Can you post full code so we can get general idea of what you are doing?

Comment: Since `row` is defined in `foreach (var row in group)`, you can't use it outside the loop.

Comment: @ekad: SO how can I use that ?? any other way

Comment: change "foreach (var row in group) " to
"foreach (var rowForEeach in group)" and rename accordingly.

Comment: put all reaming code in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this if your code scope exist till last end.

```
foreach (var row in group)
{
    sbodyMail += "<tr>" +
        "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + row["userName"].ToString() + " </td> " +
        "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + row["Doc_Type"].ToString() + " </td> " +
        "<td style='width: 100px; height: 14px;background-color:" + strcolorDet + "'>" + row["CountofDocNo"].ToString() + " </td> " +
        "</tr>";

        sbodyMail += "</table><br>" + //close of header
        "<b>THIS IS A SYSTEM GENERATED MAIL. PLEASE DO NOT REPLY </b>";
        string strExp = "";
        string startupPath = "";
        List<string> ls_attach1 = new List<string>();
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        startupPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        strExp = "RAName = '" + group.Key + "'";
        DataTable dtNew = ds.Tables[1].Select(strExp).CopyToDataTable();
        DataSet dsNew = new DataSet();
        dsNew.Tables.Add(dtNew);

        ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook(startupPath +     "\\Attachment\\Reminder_Sheet.xls", dsNew);
        ls_attach1.Add(startupPath + "\\Attachment\\Reminder_Sheet.xls");
        foreach (var attach in ls_attach1)
          {
            mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attach));
          }

        ce.SendEmail(row["userName"].ToString(), "", "", "Information on documents for processing", sbodyMail, "AUTOSQL", "Powersoft", ls_attach1, "ConnectionString");
}
```

Comment: I applied your code, but for the same user the mail is going twice. while it should go all the data in one email.. here also need to set some grouping `row["RA1_Email"].ToString()`

Comment: use breakpoints to further identify the repeating actions.

Comment: i got it done. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you get it on this line:

```
ce.SendEmail(row["userName"].ToString(), "", "", "Information on documents for processing", sbodyMail, "AUTOSQL", "Powersoft", ls_attach1, "ConnectionString");
```

The variable `row` exist only in the scope of the `foreach`. After the `}` on the `foreach` you don't have `row` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect below line is causing the error, because `row` is local to `foreach` block, you can't access outside this block.

> ce.SendEmail(**row["userName"]**.ToString(), "", "", "Information on
>   documents for processing", sbodyMail, "AUTOSQL", "Powersoft",
>   ls_attach1, "ConnectionString");

Comment: Thanks hari, I know that is the error. So how should I write that so it will be available?

Comment: You are the best person to decide the scope of `foreach` loop. Looking at your code, I think you can extend `foreach` block till last line. That means remove the `}` closing brace at the beginning and put it at the end.

Comment: can I use it like this `dt.Rows[0]["RA1_Email"].ToString()` coz i have id of sender in this ?